# How can I run a command as a different user while Fedora boots up?

Tags: linux, fedora, environment-variables, linode

I have a server which runs Fedora 19. When the server boots up, I need to run bunch of commands. I do this in `/etc/rc.d/rc.local` file. This works well. Now I need to start my `nodejs` server from this script.

I don't want to start the server program as `root`. So I tried something like the following in the `rc.local` file.

```
su myuser -c /home/myuser/project/path/prod_start.sh
```

This executes `prod_start.sh` as `myuser`. But in `prod_start.sh`, I am changing the directory to the applications root directory. It also expects some environment variables to be set before running. But since these environment variables are defined in `bash_profile` for user `myuser`, none of them took effect and the the script failed.

I'm wondering how I can run a command as a different user with all the environment variables required set for him? Should I set all these environment variables at the system level so that it is available to all users?

Comment: Why don't you just have it start when you log in? Run your script in your `~/bash_login` or `~/.Xsession` files.

Comment: It's a headless server. So `XSession` won't be there. `bash_login` is also not an option as it gets triggered when logging via ssh.

Comment: Well, you can't have it all. You could set your variables in the script itself. You could have the script start from `~/.bash_profile`. You might be able to get it to work with `su myuser bash -c "script.sh"` since that would probably read the `~/.bash_profile`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you add the '-' switch it will load myuser's profile. In other words you can have profile environment variables loaded while headless.

```
su - myuser -c "cmd_to_execute"
```